# Intents keep giving me a error even though the intents code is a C&P from a working bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have tried this which is a copy of existing code from another one of my bots that works but when i run it i get a error saying "Intents is not defined"

```
const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES,
  ],
})
```

Error:

```
ReferenceError: Intents is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, you should define the Intents by doing this:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js')
```

**Edit: You dont need to use `Discord` on discord.js v13 since its not needed, instead do it like this:**

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js')

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES,
  ],
})
```